# Changing structure of numpy array using most common value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I downscale the raster data of 4*6 size into 2*3 size using 'mode' i.e., most common value with in 2*2 pixels?

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array([
[0,0,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,1,1],
[1,0,1,1,0,1],
[1,1,0,1,0,0]])
```

The result should be:

```
result = np.array([
    [0,1,1],
    [1,1,0]])
```

Comment: I was expecting result to be full of `1`s, because in any `2x2` block there is always a `1`.

Comment: Since the maximum occurred element among '0,0,1,0' in the first 2*2 block is 0, I want to get 0 as the output.

Comment: I have asked different question for desired result as you have mentioned

Comment: @neha - I have changed "maximum occurred" to "most common" which I think is easier to understand. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472366/changing-structure-of-numpy-array-enforcing-given-value/23473616#23473616) for a full explanation. The following code will calculate your desired result.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches

data=np.array([
    [0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1,0,1],
    [1,1,0,1,0,0]])

patches = extract_patches(data, patch_shape=(2, 2), extraction_step=(2, 2))
most_frequent_number = ((patches > 0).sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1) > 2).astype(int)
print most_frequent_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go,

```
from itertools import product
from numpy import empty,argmax,bincount
res = empty((data.shape[0]/2,data.shape[1]/2))
for j,k in product(xrange(res.shape[0]),xrange(res.shape[1])):
    subvec = data[2*j:2*j+2,2*k:2*k+2].flatten()
    res[j,k]=argmax(bincount(subvec))
```

This works as long as the input `data` contains an integer number of 2x2 blocks.

Notice that a block like `[[0,0],[1,1]]` will lead `0` as result, because `argmax` returns the index of the first occurrence only. Use `res[j,k]=subvec.max()-argmax(bincount(subvec)[::-1])` if you want these 2x2 blocks  to count as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

[There appears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23472366/190597) to be more than one statistic you wish to collect about each block. Using `toblocks` (below) you can apply various computations to the last axis of `blocks` to obtain the desired statistics:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def toblocks(arr, nrows, ncols):
    h, w = arr.shape
    blocks = (arr.reshape(h // nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
              .swapaxes(1, 2)
              .reshape(h // nrows, w // ncols, ncols * nrows))
    return blocks

data=np.array([
    [0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1,0,1],
    [1,1,0,1,0,0]])

blocks = toblocks(data, 2, 2)
vals, counts = stats.mode(blocks, axis=-1)
vals = vals.squeeze()
print(vals)
# [[ 0.  1.  1.]
#  [ 1.  1.  0.]]
```